# Google Play automatic refund within 3 days

Tags: flutter, google-play

I just received a message from google play:

`We have detected that your com.curtiscollins.classytaxi package does not always confirm purchases or subscriptions via the application. As of the Billing Library 2.0 version, all purchases must be confirmed within three days, otherwise they will be refunded automatically`

I don't know what to do I didn't used the said package. should I update my flutter version or what? and when I came back to play console I can't find the message anymore

Does anyone know how to deal with this?

Comment: I am getting the same error message. Even my package name of my app is different but not sure why it is showing above message with that package name. I search entire project but nothing like that package in my app.

Comment: Did your purchases get refunded after 3 days ? Till now I didn't notice refunded in my case but for confirmation I have to wait till more than 3 days (As I just release new in app purchase version before 1 day only)

Comment: I tried updating flutter because this is what i am using and added this line to my build.gradle ```implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:2.1.0'```

Comment: I dont know if this would change anything

Comment: I just got the message today

Comment: I am using same version billingclient:billing:2.1.0, still getting message.

Comment: I didn't get any package message but users paid in-app purchase in our app, but google automatic refunds after 72 hrs & 10 mins, I don't know why this happens. i did all code as a flutter document and also added below(app/build.gradle)

dependencies {
implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:2.0.3'

but each and every time user users paid in-app purchase but google automatic refunds after 72 hrs & 10 mins.

Any solutions please? (Flutter App)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a mistake on Google's side:

https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/fh0t97/anybody_else_getting_a_weird_google_play_console/

The error message is gone now (for me and others), so I guess they fixed it :)

Comment: Yeah, I thought so too

Comment: @Tonald Drump Correct. Seems like the same.

Comment: I have the same issue, now also

Comment: I didn't get any package message but users paid in-app purchase in our app, but google automatic refunds after 72 hrs & 10 mins, I don't know why this happens. i did all code as a flutter document and also added below(app/build.gradle) dependencies { implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:2.0.3' but each and every time user users paid in-app purchase but google automatic refunds after 72 hrs & 10 mins. Any solutions please? (Flutter App)

Comment: Jignesh Patel, did you manage to solve the issue? I face the same behaviour